# How to set a multipartfile parameter as "not required" in java with spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

my problem is that I have a controller developed in Java with Spring Boot in which I edit "Portfolio" entities. Here I get the different attributes to edit this entity and also an image. My idea is that if I receive the empty parameters, it will reassign to the entity the values it had before and only modify the attributes that were sent in the form with some value.

This works correctly when I test in Postman, but when I send the image attribute as "undefined" or as "null" from the form in angular, my controller in the back end shows me an error that says:  Resolved [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'file' is not present]

My idea is to make the "file" attribute which is a MultipartFile can be empty and have no problems.

My controller is as follows:

```
 @PutMapping("/portfolio/edit-data")
public Portfolio editPortfolio (@RequestParam("image")MultipartFile image,
                                  @ModelAttribute("port") Portfolio port,
                                  BindingResult result){
    
    Portfolio portOriginal = portServ.buscarPortfolio(Long.valueOf(1));
    
    if(!image.isEmpty()){
        String rutaAbsoluta = "C:\\Users\\Paul";
        try{
            byte[] bytesImg = image.getBytes();
            Path fullPath = Paths.get(absolutePath + "//" + image.getOriginalFilename());
            Files.write(fullPath, bytesImg);
            port.setImage(image.getOriginalFilename());
        }catch (IOException e){
        }
    }else{
        port.setImage(portOriginal.getImagen());
    }
    
    if("".equals(port.getName())){
        port.setName(portOriginal.getName());
    }
    if("".equals(port.getTitle())){
        port.setTitle(portOriginal.getTitle());
    }
    if("".equals(port.getIntroduction())){
        port.setIntroduction(portOriginal.getIntroduction());
    }
    if("".equals(port.getFooter())){
        port.setFooter(portOriginal.getFooter());
    }
 
    return portServ.editarPortfolio(port, Long.valueOf(1));
}
```

The following query is correct in Postman. So it would be useful to be able to submit an empty file in a form from angular.

[Postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qgdkz.png)

Comment: Did you try `@RequestParam(required = false)`?

Comment: Yes, I tried to put @RequestParam(value="image", defaultValue= "" ,required=false but if I don't send the corresponding parameter I get as result a 500 error that says "Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile'"

Comment: Why did you add `defaultValue`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `@RequestParam(required = false)` (no need for the name to be specified with the value param, because spring takes the variable name by default and in your case they're the same)

You're method definition would look like this:

```java
@PutMapping("/portfolio/edit-data")
public Portfolio editPortfolio (@RequestParam(required = false) MultipartFile image,
                                @ModelAttribute Portfolio port,
                                BindingResult result)
```

Comment: It doesn't work either, I get an error saying java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Well then check if the image is null?

Comment: Yes, I haven't found the solution yet

Comment: Im confused. I guess your image is null since we set it to required false and now you would just add `image != null` to your first if condition and it should work. Otherwise an exception would be usefull or even a new question since ur inital question "How to set a multipartfile parameter as "not required" in java with spring boot?" got answered.

Comment: You were right my friend, I made the conditional wrong before commenting. With image!=null it worked perfectly. Thank you very much! You're great!

Comment: If it works I would appreciate if you accept the answer